# Does clang provide an unlink implementation?

Tags: c++, clang, clang++, unlink

I am trying to compile a library using clang. The library makes calls to 'unlink', which is not defined by clang:

```
libmv/src/third_party/OpenExif/src/ExifImageFileWrite.cpp:162:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'unlink'; did you mean 'inline'?
            unlink( mTmpImageFile.c_str() ) ;
```

My question is, what is the clang equivalent of unlink? As I see it, the path forward would be to #define unlink somewhere with an equivalent routine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no "Clang equivalent". Neither GCC nor Clang have ever been responsible for defining [`unlink`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html), though they do probably distribute the POSIX headers which do (I don't recall specifically where POSIX headers come from).

Unfortunately, this appears to be a bug with the library you're using; the OpenExif developers failed to include the correct headers. Different C++ implementations may internally `#include` various headers for their own purposes, which has apparently masked this bug on your previous toolchain.

You can hack your copy and/or submit a patch to add:

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

Comment: I will fix this when I get a chance, but for anyone with the exact same problem (specifically with OpenExif), the #include for unistd.h is #ifdef'd for Linux only. The fix is to include __APPLE__ in the condition.

Comment: I think the more proper way might be to add `#define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1` into ExifComp.h?

Comment: Normally third party libraries can be configured for a specific platform, and part of this configuration step would be to `#define HAVE_UNISTD_H` to `0` or `1`.